# All received VLAN packets are becoming Error Vlan Packets

Tags: linux, network-programming, virtual-machine, ethernet, libpcap

I am trying to send and receive VLAN packets, But every packet I am receiving on that mac becoming an error packet. 
Can some one explain me the reasons for a packet to be received as error.

here is the status...

`Information about Ethernet interface 4, 10G_PLANE_A:
                     Device State: UP
                       Link State: UP
                       Link Speed: 10000
                      Duplex Mode: FULL
                     Flow Control: DISABLED
                                ------
                      MAC address: 02:00:01:02:08:40
                 Packets Received: 5662
                   Bytes Received: 449816
         Errored Packets Received: 0
           Packets Without Client: 5655
                     Packets Sent: 1211
                       Bytes Sent: 41174
            Vlan Packets Received: 1761
                Vlan Packets Sent: 1211
      Error Vlan Packets Received: 1761
          Error Vlan Packets Sent: 0
                        Wred drop: 0`

The packet i am sending is....

`0000  02 00 01 02 08 40 00 01  ec 69 c7 b5 81 00 80 b4   .....@.. .i......
0010  82 12 01 00 00 10 ab ba  ac dc 07 ff 00 10 e9 ab   ........ ........
0020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........ ........
0030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 31 0b fa 74   ........ ....1..t`

I tried changing VLNID but no use with that...

Thanks in advance
Murali krishna.

Answer (score 1):

Your vlan 802.1Q header is: 0x8100 80b4, so your vlan id should be 0xb4 = 180 decimal

See 802.1Q header here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1Q

The ethertype/length is right after 0x8100 80b4, so it would be 8212.
Since 8212 is larger than 0x05DC, so it's considered as an ethertype but i can't find 0x8212 as a valid etype.

So likely your packet is missing the length field.  You should add the length field (2 bytes) right before 0x8212.  Try it out and see if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After changing the packet format also i am getting the same result. The packet format is changed as below `0000  02 00 01 02 08 40 00 01  ec 69 c7 b5 81 00 80 b4   .....@.. .i......
0010  05 dc 81 00 01 00 00 f0  ab ba ac dc 07 ff 80 10   ........ ........
0020  00 e1 06 63 00 7d 00 00  03 e9 00 da 00 00 01 00   ...c.}.. ........
0030  01 01 00 02 01 00 03 01  00 04 01 00 ea 4b 09 af   ........ .....K..`

Comment: Instead of 0x05DC, u should put the actual length of your packet. 0x05DC is just a check to determine whether or not it's a packet length or ethertype.